# Boostrap Menu List Item Transparent on Hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap drop down menu where the child list items keep turning transparent when I hover over any of the items:

[image]

When I am not hovering over the child list items, the menu retains it's original font color and size
[image]

Here is my CSS code:

`.dropdown-menu li {
    width: 160px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
}`

How do I prevent the child list items from turning transparent upon hovering?

```
.dropdown-menu li:hover{ color:black}
```

did not work

Here is the code to create the menu

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax({
    url: 'MenuHandler.ashx',
    method: 'get',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        buildmenu($('.menu'), data);
        $('.menu').menu();

    }
})

var lastliElement; // if more occurance append to the last element

function buildmenu(parent, items) {
    var tabOccurance = [];
    $.each(items, function () {
        var nbOccurnace = countOccurance(this.MenuText, items);
        // search if occurance text alredy exist
        if (tabOccurance.indexOf(this.MenuText) == -1) { // this doesn't work on ecma6 and above
            var length = this.ParentID == null ? this.List.length : nbOccurnace;
            var li = $('<li><a href="Cars/Acura/car.aspx">' + this.MenuText + '(' + length + ')' + '</a></li>');
            lastliElement = li;
            if (!this.Active) {
                li.addclass('ui-state-disabled');
            }

            li.appendTo(parent);

        }
        if (nbOccurnace > 1)
            tabOccurance.push(this.MenuText);

        if (this.List && this.List.length > 0) {

            var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
            ul.appendTo(lastliElement);
            buildmenu(ul, this.List);
        }
    });
}
// to conunt occurance of menuText
function countOccurance(MenuText, list) {
    var count = 0
    $.each(list, function () {
        if (this.MenuText === MenuText)
            count++;
    });
    return count;
}
```

});

Comment: Can you share the full code? May be on hover you are giving different styles.

Comment: Select dropdown from dev tool choose :hover event in that you will find `:hover` css in that..overwrite it..may b it will b like `.dropdown-menu li:hover{ color:black}`

Answer (score 0):

You could set you own styles for the hover. It is done this way:

```
.dropdown-menu li: hover{
    color:black !important; /* or the one you want */
    /* more styles */
}
```